# DSC Automation doesn't run until instance has been restarted, but says it's compliant

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc, azure-automation

I am trying to enroll fresh Windows Server 2016 servers into in Azure Automation, as DSC nodes. I am using the script [here](https://github.com/justeat/PowerShellDSCUtils/blob/master/Version5DSC.ps1) to do so. After the script runs a report appears in Automation next to the node, labelled as 'Consistency' with the status 'Compliant'. However, the report appears to have done nothing, no resources are generated, despite the configuration being correct.

I've discovered that it does nothing, until I restart the machine, then PowerShell DSC starts running again, and generates all the resources as expected. (See screenshots of the two reports below).

I have checked the raw log, and am receiving this message on the first report:

```
Registration of the Dsc Agent with the server https://ne-agentservice-prod-1.azure-automation.net/accounts/(removed) failed. The underlying error is: The attempt to register Dsc Agent with AgentId (removed) with the server https://ne-agentservice-prod-1.azure-automation.net/accounts/(removed)/Nodes(AgentId=\\(removed)) returned unexpected response code BadRequest.
```

I can see this in the logs:

```
Performing the operation \"Start-DscConfiguration: \r\nSendMetaConfigurationApply\" on target \"MSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager\".\nVERBOSE: Perform operation 'Invoke CimMethod' with following parameters, \r\n''methodName' = SendMetaConfigurationApply,'className' = \r\nMSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager,'namespaceName' = \r\nroot/Microsoft/Windows/DesiredStateConfiguration'.\nVERBOSE: An LCM method call arrived from computer (removed) with user sid\r\n S-1-5-18.\n\tFailed to apply SetupLCM DSC Configuration to self!\n\tError details: Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException: Cannot invoke the Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager cmdlet. The Consistency Check or Pull cmdlet is in progress and must return before Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager can be invoked. Use -Force option if that is available to cancel the current operation.
```

and this in Event Viewer:[image: Event Viewer]

I can't work out if there's a bug in Automation, the script I'm using to enrol or where the issue actually lies. I don't understand why a restart fixes the issue either, when I first started testing enrolling to DSC it didn't require a restart.

[image: ![First Report]

[image: Second Report]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. Azure Automation doesn't officially support partial configurations yet. You can vote for the support at [Azure Automation UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/13704216-provide-support-for-dsc-partial-configuration)

That said, you may take a look at [DSC Composite Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/authoringresourcecomposite) as almost all cases of partial configuration can be done through it.

Comment: I'm not using a partial configuration at the moment. Are there any other Automation issues that could be causing this?

Comment: The script in the github link you provided seems to generate partial configs. The comment on top of that script also provided some explanation.